# Python Subset dataframe with another dataframe

Tags: python, r

I'm transitioning from R to Python and trying to subset a dataframe with a field in another dataframe. What would be the Python Equivalent for this R code:

```
final_solution <- subset(df1, item %in% df2$item)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)?

Comment: yes i'm using pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
df1[(df1.item).isin(df2.item)]
```

Using a reproducible example (with `pandas`)

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'item' :  [1, 2, 3, 4],
                           'fruit' : ['mango', 'apple', 'banana', 'mango']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'item' : [1, 2]})

print(df1[(df1.item).isin(df2.item)])
```

gives the output

```
#    fruit  item
#0  mango     1
#1  apple     2
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you are using pandas, you could [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html):

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['df1_col', 'df2_col'])
```